In this circuit, why does the 2k ohm resistor have zero voltage and current? It has a path to the battery, so why doesn't any electricity cross it?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Why is this happening? Isn't electricity supposed to take all possible paths? Is solving for this circuit's equivalent resistance possible? Thank you in advance!

in reality, the voltage would be near zero, but not zero, because of the resistance of the wire

Nice 3D picture. +1 for the original idea!

It takes all possible paths, but in this case it is not a possible path.
In your circuit; both ends of the resistor are connected to a same node. It means the resistor has 0V over it. And from Ohm's law we know that 0V over a resistor means 0A.

I think that I understand what you mean. So if the wire wasn't ideal and had a resistance, then would that resistor have some current?

@RReddy Yes; a practical non-superconducting wire would have non-zero resistance, thus there would be non-zero voltage over the resistor and non-zero current through it. But in practice you can ignore it in most circuits. In some sensitive circuits, you might not be able to ignore it, and in the most sensitive circuits, even the effect of the junction between wire and resistor must be considered. These real world effects are ignored by your simulator.

@RReddy yes.Change the wire to a 200-ohm resistor and see what happens. Then replace it with 20 ohms, then 2 ohms, then 0.2 ohms. Now extrapolate to 0 ohms :)
